# minified css getting overwritten by bootstrap cdn in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, w3-total-cache

i'm using a plugin called "w3 total cache" on wordpress that minifies my style.css (which is located in my theme folder). the problem is that in function.php i enqueued the boostrap cdn and style.css correctly like this:

```
function bootstrap() { 
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css' ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js',  array('jquery') );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap');



function maincss() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'maincss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'maincss');
```

BUT, whenever my page loads the style.css gets minified right after the head tags and bootstrap stays below overwriting all my rules...

this is the website i'm working on: http://bootstraptest.co.nf

if you move the first stylesheet right after bootstrap you can see the button working and the header getting placed correctly.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46651286/3983624

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dependency attribute of wp_enqueue_style
See the documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

```
    function bootstrap() { 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js',  array('jquery') );

    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap');
function maincss() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'maincss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' , array('bootstrap-css') );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'maincss');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it's not working still :(

Comment: Sorry.. My mistake.. can you check the updated comment above

Comment: this happens: Fatal error: Unknown: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in Unknown on line 0 lol

Comment: the problem is that maincss gets minified right after the head tag, and since bootstrap doesnt get minified as a cdn it load after, so it overwrites my style.  

here's the code: 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://bootstraptest.co.nf/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/M9D3yCwoLkktCslIzU3VLy6pzEnVMUAVTC4u1s8qLE0tqtRLK83JCUhMTwUA.css" media="all">

  <link rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css-css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=4.2.3" type="text/css" media="all">

hope it's more clear :) @Anil Dhull