# minified css is getting overwritten by bootstrap cdn using w3tc

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

i'm using a plugin called "w3 total cache" on wordpress that minifies my style.css (which is located in my theme folder). the problem is that in function.php i enqueued the boostrap cdn and style.css correctly like this:

```
   function bootstrap() { 
   wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css','https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css' ); 
   wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js',  array('jquery') );

   }
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap');



   function maincss() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'maincss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'maincss');
```

BUT, whenever my page loads the style.css gets minified right after the head tags and bootstrap stays below overwriting all my rules...

this is the website i'm working on: http://bootstraptest.co.nf

if you move the first stylesheet right after bootstrap you can see the button working and the header getting placed correctly.

Comment: you can use priority to choose the order `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', $name, $priority);`

Comment: already tryed that. doesn't work

Comment: I don't understand what doesn't work. can you explain what doesn't work on the website and the result you wish

Answer (score 0):

In `header.php` add `<!-- W3TC-include-css -->` code after `wp_head()`

Like this:

```
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <!-- W3TC-include-css -->
</head>
```

This will cause the mined w3tc file to appear after your bootstrap call